# Flutter - how to prevent "onChanged" being called in a text field if it becomes empty?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField that performs a call to a function that does a calculation on each text change. How do I prevent that call being made if the user clears out the field?

Example input field:

```
           Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    focusNode: _bigBlindFocusNode,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      setState(() {
                        _calculateTotalPotPreflop();
                      });
                    },
                    controller: _textEditControllerBigBlind,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Big Blind',
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )),
```

The function getting called:

```
_calculateTotalPotPreflop() {
    print("total pot: " + totalPotPreflop.toInt().toString());
    if (_bigBlindAnteCheckbox == true) {
      totalPotPreflop = int.tryParse(_textEditControllerSmallBlind.text) +
          int.tryParse(_textEditControllerBigBlind.text) +
          int.tryParse(_textEditControllerAnte.text);
    } else {
      totalPotPreflop = int.tryParse(_textEditControllerSmallBlind.text) +
          int.tryParse(_textEditControllerBigBlind.text) +
          (int.tryParse(_textEditControllerNumberPlayers.text) *
              int.tryParse(_textEditControllerAnte.text));
    }
  }
```

The error only occurs when I click on a field, enter in some text, the calculation performs, then use backspace to clear out the field.

The error returned in console is:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets ===============================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while calling onChanged:
The method '_addFromInteger' was called on null.
```

The program still compiles & runs just fine, and there are no obvious errors on the UI to the user. It's only what I see in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the condition before calling the function and setState.

```dart
onChanged: (text) {
  if (text != null || text.isNotEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      _calculateTotalPotPreflop();
    });
  }
},
```